# как зафиксировать блок в блоке со скролом при прокрутке?

Tags: html, css

имеется блок `div` со скроллом. внутри него много текста и блок, который должен быть зафиксирован при скролле. как это сделать?

```
<div class="scroll">
  <div>text</div>
   ...
  <div class="fixed-block"></div>
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Были попытки дать `fixed-block` `position: fixed`, но он становится фиксированным относительно окна браузера.
Были попытки дать `fixed-block` `position: absolute`, блок становиться поверх всего текста (как мне и надо), но но при скролле он тоже улетает.
как быть?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете создать контейнер для скролла, и уже в нем располагать элементы абсолютно. Например, так:

```css
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
div.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
div.fixed-block {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed-block"></div>
  <div class="scroll">
    <p>Не поддавайтесь панике, даже если очень хочется. В самых разных уголках мира маглов вдруг начали появляться следы волшебства. Мы беспокоимся, что в скором времени это заметят даже крайне безразличные маглы. Волшебники и волшебницы, нам нужна ваша помощь!</p>
    <p> Если не обуздать это бедствие, наступят страшные времена, как сами знаете когда при Сами-Знаете-Ком. Повторите знакомые вам заклинания, берите палочку и вступайте в наши ряды!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```